# не работает валидация форм на java script

Tags: javascript, html, css, form, popup

Валидацию делаю впервые, поэтому прошу сильно не критиковать, от помощи и откорректированному коду буду рада:). При необходимости могу показать часть html разметки форм, чтобы было понятней. В консоле множество ошибок, которые я не могу понять как и что исправлять:(

```js
const showInputError = (config, formElement, inputElement) => {
  const errorElement = formElement.querySelector(`#${inputElement.id}-error`);
  inputElement.classList.add(config, inputErrorClass);
  errorElement.textContent = '';
}

const hideInputError = (config, formElement, inputElement) => {
  const errorElement = formElement.querySelector(`#${inputElement.id}-error`);
  inputElement.classList.remove(config, inputErrorClass);
  errorElement.textContent = '';
}

const checkInputValidity = (config, formElement, inputElement) => {
  if (!inputElement.validity.valid) {
    showInputError(config, formElement, inputElement, inputElement.validationMessage);
  } else {
    hideInputError(config, formElement, inputElement);
  }
}

hasInvalidInput = (inputList) => {
  return inputList.some((inputElement) => {
    return !inputElement.validity.valid;
  });
}

const toggleButtonState = (config, inputList, ButtonElement) => {
  if (hasInvalidInput(inputList)) {
    ButtonElement.classList.add(config, inactiveButtonClass);
    ButtonElement.setAttribute('disabled', true);
  } else {
    ButtonElement.classList.remove(config, inactiveButtonClass);
    ButtonElement.removeAttribute('disabled');
  }
}

function setEventListeners(inputSelector, formElement) {
  const inputList = Array.from(formElement.querySelectorAll(inputSelector));
  const ButtonElement = formElement.querySelector(submitButtonSelector);
  toggleButtonState(config, inputList, ButtonElement);
  inputList.forEach((inputElement) => {
    inputElement.addEventListener('input', () => {
      checkInputValidity(config, formElement, inputElement);
      toggleButtonState(config, inputList, ButtonElement);
    });
  });
}

const enableValidation = ({
  formSelector,
  inputSelector
}) => {
  const formList = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(formSelector));
  formList.forEach((formElement) => {
    formElement.addEventListener('submit', function(evt) {
      evt.preventDefault();
    });
    setEventListeners(inputSelector, formElement);
  });
}

enableValidation({
  formSelector: '.form',
  inputSelector: '.form__item',
  submitButtonSelector: '.form__button',
  inactiveButtonClass: 'form__button_disabled',
  inputErrorClass: 'form__item_invalid',
  errorClass: 'popup__error_visible'
});
```

```css
.form__button_disabled {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  border: 1px solid black;
  opacity: 0.2;
}

.form__button_disabled:hover {
  opacity: 0.2;
  cursor: default;
}

.form__item-error {
  min-height: 12px;
  font-family: 'Inter', 'Arial', sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 1.2;
  color: #FF0000;
}
```

```html
<div class="popup" id="popup-profile">
  <div class="popup__container">
    <button class="popup__close-button" id="close-button" type="button" value="close"></button>
    <form class="form" id="form" name="form" method="post">
      <h2 class="form__title">Редактировать профиль</h2>
      <fieldset class="form__user" id="profile__fields">

        <input class="form__item" type="text" id="profile__name" name="profile__name" placeholder="Введите ваше имя" autocomplete="off" value="Жак-Ив Кусто" minlength="2" maxlength="40" required>
        <span class="form__item-error" id="profile__name-input-error"></span>

        <input class="form__item" type="text" id="profile__paragraph" name="profile__paragraph" placeholder="Ваша профессия" minlength="2" maxlength="200" autocomplete="off" value="Исследователь океана" required>
        <span class="form__item-error" id="profile__paragraph-input-error"></span>

      </fieldset>
      <button class="form__button" type="submit" name="profile__save" value="Сохранить">Сохранить</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- попап ELements-photo -->
<div class="popup popup-photo">
  <div class="popup__container">
    <button class="popup__close-button" id="close-Btn" type="button" value="close"></button>
    <form class="form" id="button-form" name="form" method="post">
      <h2 class="form__title">Новое место</h2>
      <fieldset class="form__user">

        <input class="form__item" type="text" id="elements__name" name="elements__name" placeholder="Название" minlength="1" maxlength="30" required>
        <span class="form__item-error" id="elements__name-input-error"></span>

        <input class="form__item" type="url" id="elements__image" name="elements__image" placeholder="Ссылка на картинку" required>

        <span class="form__item-error" id="elements-image-error"></span>

      </fieldset>
      <button class="form__button" type="submit" name="profile__save" value="Сохранить">Сохранить</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Как минимум у вас опечатка в названии переменной `chowInputError =`.

Comment: опечатку исправила:) showInputError

Comment: добавьте html css

Comment: html добавила, только css несколько добавила, т.к. все разбито по БЭМ.

Answer (score 0):

Надеюсь это решит вашу задачу.
У вас было много пропущенных ошибок. Проверте и вы всё сами поймёте!

```js
const showInputError = (config, formElement, inputElement, inputErrorClass) => {
  const errorElement = formElement.querySelector(`#${inputElement.id}-input-error`);
  inputElement.classList.add(config, inputErrorClass);
  errorElement.textContent = "";
};

const hideInputError = (config, formElement, inputElement, inputErrorClass) => {
  const errorElement = formElement.querySelector(`#${inputElement.id}-input-error`);
  inputElement.classList.remove(config, inputErrorClass);
  errorElement.textContent = "";
};

const checkInputValidity = (config, formElement, inputElement, inputErrorClass) => {
  if (!inputElement.validity.valid) {
    showInputError(config, formElement, inputElement, inputErrorClass, inputElement.validationMessage);
  } else {
    hideInputError(config, formElement, inputElement, inputErrorClass);
  }
};

hasInvalidInput = (inputList) => {
  return inputList.some((inputElement) => {
    return !inputElement.validity.valid;
  });
};

const toggleButtonState = (config, inputList, ButtonElement) => {
  if (hasInvalidInput(inputList)) {
    ButtonElement.classList.add(config, "inactiveButtonClass");
    ButtonElement.setAttribute("disabled", true);
  } else {
    ButtonElement.classList.remove(config, "inactiveButtonClass");
    ButtonElement.removeAttribute("disabled");
  }
};

function setEventListeners(
  inputSelector,
  formElement,
  submitButtonSelector,
  config,
  inputErrorClass
) {
  const inputList = Array.from(formElement.querySelectorAll(inputSelector));
  const ButtonElement = formElement.querySelector(submitButtonSelector);
  toggleButtonState(config, inputList, ButtonElement);
  inputList.forEach((inputElement) => {
    inputElement.addEventListener("input", () => {
      
      checkInputValidity(config, formElement, inputElement, inputErrorClass);
      toggleButtonState(config, inputList, ButtonElement);
    });
  });
}

const enableValidation = (params) => {
  const formList = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(params.formSelector));
  formList.forEach((formElement) => {
    formElement.addEventListener("submit", function (evt) {
      evt.preventDefault();
    });

    setEventListeners(
      params.inputSelector,
      formElement,
      params.submitButtonSelector,
      params.config,
      params.inputErrorClass
    );
  });
};

enableValidation({
  formSelector: ".form",
  inputSelector: ".form__item",
  submitButtonSelector: ".form__button",
  inactiveButtonClass: "form__button_disabled",
  inputErrorClass: "form__item_invalid",
  errorClass: "popup__error_visible",
  config: "somthing"
});
```

```css
.form__button_disabled {
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    border: 1px solid black;
    opacity: 0.2;
  }
  .form__button_disabled:hover {
    opacity: 0.2;
    cursor: default;
  }
.form__item-error {
    min-height: 12px;
    font-family: 'Inter', 'Arial', sans-serif;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 1.2;
    color: #FF0000;
}
```

```html
<div class="popup" id="popup-profile">
  <div class="popup__container">
    
    <button class="popup__close-button" id="close-button">
      Close
    </button>
    
    <form class="form"
          id="form"
          name="form"
          method="post">
      
      <h2 class="form__title">
        Редактировать профиль
      </h2>
      
      <fieldset class="form__user" id="profile__fields">

        <input class="form__item"
               type="text"
               id="profile__name"
               name="profile__name"
               placeholder="Введите ваше имя"
               autocomplete="off"
               value="Жак-Ив Кусто"
               minlength="2"
               maxlength="40"
               required>
        
        <span class="form__item-error" id="profile__name-input-error"></span>

        <input class="form__item"
               type="text"
               id="profile__paragraph"
               name="profile__paragraph"
               placeholder="Ваша профессия"
               minlength="2"
               maxlength="200"
               autocomplete="off"
               value="Исследователь океана"
               required>
        
        <span class="form__item-error" id="profile__paragraph-input-error"></span>

      </fieldset>
      
      <button class="form__button"
              type="submit"
              name="profile__save"
              value="Сохранить">
        Сохранить
      </button>
      
    </form>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- попап ELements-photo -->
<div class="popup popup-photo">
  <div class="popup__container">
    <button class="popup__close-button"
            id="close-Btn"
            type="button"
            value="close">
      Close
    </button>
    
    <form class="form"
          id="button-form"
          name="form"
          method="post">
      
      <h2 class="form__title">Новое место</h2>
      <fieldset class="form__user">

        <input class="form__item"
               type="text"
               id="elements__name"
               name="elements__name"
               placeholder="Название"
               minlength="1"
               maxlength="30"
               required>
        
        <span class="form__item-error" id="elements__name-input-error"></span>

        <input class="form__item"
               type="url"
               id="elements__image"
               name="elements__image"
               placeholder="Ссылка на картинку"
               required>

        <span class="form__item-error" id="elements-image-error"></span>

      </fieldset>
      <button class="form__button"
              type="submit"
              name="profile__save"
              value="Сохранить">
        Сохранить
      </button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Меня зовут Иван. Я недавно начал изучать js, и сталкнулся с этой же задачей на Практикуме. Помогите пожалуйста разобраться на примере вашего кода. Подскажите, в предложенном вами решении не совсем понятно, от куда берется config. Если бы в начале кода было бы что то вроде:

const config = {

formSelector: ".form",
inputSelector: ".form__item",
submitButtonSelector: ".form__button",
inactiveButtonClass: "form__button_disabled",
inputErrorClass: "form__item_invalid",
errorClass: "popup__error_visible"
}

Мне бы было понятно. Подскажите это пропущен кусочек когда, или я не правильно понимаю логику?

Comment: Это не ответ, а комментарий.